# grails test-app -coverage doesn't include coverage for functional tests in forked mode

Tags: grails

I'm having trouble understanding Grails forked mode and how it's impacting the code coverage reports when I'm running `grails test-app -coverage`.  I am using Grails 2.3.1.

I turned off forked mode for the test configuration

```
grails.project.fork = [... test: false  ... ]
```

And unit tests show up in the coverage report.

However, coverage from functional tests is NOT included in the Cobertura output.

If I turn off forked mode for the `run` option as well, then I *do* get coverage from functional tests in the Cobertura report.

Questions:

- why does forked mode for `run` impact the coverage output?  aren't the same instrumented classes also deployed to the embedded Tomcat?
- is there a way to use forked mode normally for run-app, but not when launched incidental to `test-app -functional` for tests?

Answer (score 2):

The problem should be reported at https://github.com/beckje01/grails-code-coverage/issues.

Yes, there is a way to use forked mode for run-app but not for test-app.  In `BuildConfig.groovy` you can do something like this:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    test: false,
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]
```

That probably doesn't affect functional tests in the way that you want, but does affect other tests.

**EDIT:**

See https://github.com/beckje01/grails-code-coverage/issues/11

That probably doesn't help with functional tests and may need to be addressed as a separate problem.

Comment: I would report the issue agains the coverage plugin but it may end up being related to code in the functional-test plugin and the way that it launches the app.

Comment: changing test:false will not help with functional tests.  That seems to be driven by the `run` setting.  Is there a way I can change the `run` setting conditionally?

Comment: I am not using the functional test plugin - I am using Geb under tests/functional - the issue is not in Geb but in grails test-app where it starts the application inline

Comment: "the issue is not in Geb but in grails test-app".  My mistake.  Best of luck.

Comment: If the problem is in grails test-app, file a JIRA at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS/ and I will take a look.

Comment: from Grails JIRA, it looks like it is by design that `grails test-app -functional` should start the application in the same forked mode as `grails run-app`: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPTOMCAT-15

Comment: Does `grails -Dgrails.project.fork.run=false test-app functional:` work?